# Angular9 window.open() returns 400 bad request

Tags: angular, http, error-handling, http-status-code-400

I'm runnig below code on my local succesfully but in prod environment I'm getting bad request 400 error. Any idea about it ?

Bad request URL => `https://xx.xxxxxxx.com/minimal/print-report-movement/%7B%22vehicleIds%22:[20084256],%22vehiclePlates%22:[%2234%20AGV%20918%22],%22startDate%22:%222021-12-23T21:00:00.000Z%22,%22finishDate%22:%222021-12-24T20:59:00.000Z%22,%22days%22:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],%22notifyLocationInfo%22:false,%22notifyStopAlarmInfo%22:false,%22notifyIgniInfo%22:false,%22notifyIdleAlarmInfo%22:false,%22notifyIdleInfo%22:false,%22notifyMoveAlarmInfo%22:false,%22notifySpeedAlarmInfo%22:false,%22startHourMin%22:%222022-01-20T21:00:00.000Z%22,%22finishHourMin%22:%222022-01-21T20:59:00.000Z%22,%22timeZoneOffset%22:180,%22reqType%22:%22print%22%7D`

Local => environment.minimalUrl is 'http://localhost:4200/minimal/'

Prod => environment.minimalUrl is 'http://container01.xxxx.local:6200/minimal/'

```
getPrint(_data: ReportCriterionModel): void {
            var h = window.innerHeight * 0.8;
            let w = window.innerWidth * 0.8;
            let left = window.innerWidth * 0.1;
            let top = window.innerHeight * 0.1;
    
            window.open(
                `${environment.minimalUrl}print-report-movement/${JSON.stringify(_data)}`,
                'popupWindow', `width=${w},height=${h},left=${left},top=${top},scrollbars=yes`
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an indication of a client error where server will not process the request due something that is perceived to be invalid e.g. malformed request syntax or invalid request message framing and etc.

There are a few things you can check in order to find the root cause.

- Web server might look for a specific custom request header to process
  the request. Check if a custom header is missing.
- Check if you are accessing the URL correctly. You can check if there
  are malformed characters in the request.
- Lastly, check if you are using an invalid or expired local cookie.
  Logout and log into the application.

Comment: Thank you. We think that problem is that our url is too long for IIS .